# Using a loop with xargs in one line

Tags: loops, xargs, tcsh

I am using tcsh. I want to output:

```
mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4
```

Where of course the maximum number of dirs is variable. The point is they contain the incrementing variable from a loop in their names. I have a feeling I should use xargs. I just want to be able to use a simple loop, and do it all in one line if possible. Is this possible? My feeling is it will be something like:

```
loop here | xargs mkdir
```

but I am just not able to make my syntax work.

edit: I figured out how to do it with multiple lines of input. Anyone know how to make the following into a single line input?

```
for i in {1..5}
do
echo -n " dir$i"
done \
| xargs mkdir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
foreach a ( `seq 1 1 10` )
  mkdir dir$a
end
```

or

```
seq -f 'dir%.0f' -s ' ' 1 1 10 | xargs mkdir
```

Comment: I get this error: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Also, doesn't that just do multiple outputs? I want a single mkdir and multiple arguments.

Comment: do you have the seq from coreutils?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they works both. Btw, what tcsh version do you have? tcsh --version

Comment: tcsh 6.14.00 (Astron) 2005-03-25 (x86_64-unknown-linux)

Comment: first example copy/paste tested and works on: (debian 5.0.9)tcsh 6.14.00 (Astron) 2005-03-25  and (openSuse 11.3)tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14

Comment: I copy pasted too. Oh well. Thanks for the answers.